# The largest Saturday number

Tags: mathematics, number-theory, number-property

No weekend love yet shown, therefore I will fix that.

A Saturday number is a number in which for all $1 \le i \le l$, where $l$ is the length of the number, the first $l$ digits (from the left) divide by $l$. For example, 3816547290 is a valid Saturday number for 10, so your answer must, at minimum, be larger than or equal to that. Leading zeroes are not permitted.

If there is a largest Saturday number, *find it*, else, if there are an infinite number of them, *find an example with 200 digits.*

Comment: should that be the first i digits divide by i?

Comment: Can you clarify whether "first" digits count from the left or right?

Comment: @IanMacdonald From the left.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [Find the largest number having this property.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/411897/355349)

Comment: I feel like the problem statement could be clearer. You have "`l` is the length of the number" and set the inequality equation so `i` will be the first digits. But the rest of the statement uses `l` for the first digits and `i` is never mentioned again. I would rephrase as *"A Saturday number is a number with `l` digits where, for all $1 \leq i \leq l$ it holds that the first $i$ digits divide by $i$."* Another edit is pending and I don't have enough rep to edit directly, so leaving as a comment.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it already has an answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411897/find-the-largest-number-having-this-property (cross-site duplicate)

Comment: @Steve Voting to leave open; that's not a reason to close a question on *this* site.

Comment: @Randal'Thor is there a meta guideline for that? Btw there is a same issue with https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/110490/34043

Comment: @JanIvan In general, I'd say what exists or not on another site shouldn't at all affect a question's closability on this site. Same way as we don't close/migrate questions just for being on-topic on another site, if they're also on-topic here. Not sure about any meta guideline though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The more common name for a Saturday number is

> a [Polydivisible number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydivisible_number)

There is a good argument for believing that they cannot grow to any length:

> If you remove the last digit from a Polydivisible number you get a smaller Polydivisible number. Conversely, you can only get a length $n$ Polydivisible number if you append a digit $d$ to a length $n-1$ Polydivisible number $q$. For that to work you need $q,d$ to be such that $10q+d\equiv 0 \bmod n$. Only $10$ values are possible for the digit $d$, so no more than $10$ out of $n$ residue classes for $10q \bmod n$ allow this extension to work. Assuming that each residue class is equally probable, the probability that you can extend a Polydivisible number is $10/n$, so when $n>10$ you expected there to be fewer Polydivisible numbers remaining each time you try to extend them.

The longest Saturday number is:

> 3608528850368400786036725, which is 25 digits long.

To be honest, I wrote a computer program to find it, and only found the common name for this type of number after I googled the number that I found. These numbers are listed in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A109032).

For those interested, here is the simple C# program I wrote:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Numerics;

  namespace TempProg
  {
     class PSEsaturday
     {
        public static void Main()
        {
           List<BigInteger> current = new List<BigInteger>();
           List<BigInteger> next = new List<BigInteger>();

           for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
              current.Add(new BigInteger(i));

           int length = 1;
           while(current.Count > 0)
           {
              length++;
              foreach (var n in current)
              {
                 for( int d=0; d<=9; d++)
                 {
                    var n2 = n * 10 + d;
                    if(n2 % length == 0)
                    {
                       next.Add(n2);
                       Console.WriteLine(n2);
                    }
                 }
              }
              var t = current;
              current = next;
              next = t;
              next.Clear();
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Perfect proof and answer - this is getting accepted.

Comment: Nice! Could you share a pastebin link or something to your code too? I'm just curious to see how you did that.

Comment: @KabirKanhaArora I added my program code.

Comment: Curiously the OEIS cites the stackexchange network, bringing this full circle!

Comment: Now that proof would imply that it might be possible to get bigger if you don't restrict yourself to base 10.  I could see a potential OEIS for largest number in base N that meets the criteria...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman In my post I linked to the OEIS sequence for the largest base n numbers. There is also [A109783](https://oeis.org/A109783) which gives the number of base-n digits of these numbers. It says there that it is conjectured to always be finite length (what I gave is not an airtight proof since it is probabilistic and uses assumptions) and also that the length is approximately n*e digits.

Comment: OEIS really needs to add the ability to post lists in non base-10 format for situations like this.